# How to run QPython over adb shell

Tags: android, shell, adb, qpython

I installed the QPython on my (rooted) phone. I'm having trouble, however, running the python binary over the adb shell (busybox).

I can run the python binary after setting:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/vendor/lib:/system/lib:/data/data/com.hipipal.qpyplus/files
```

However, I cannot import any module from the standard library even setting $PYTHONPATH

```
export PYTHONPATH=/data/data/com.hipipal.qpyplus/files/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

I found a piece of advice how to run QPython in different terminal on the community wiki ( http://wiki.qpython.org/hacker/#how-to-execute-qpythons-python-in-other-terminals ), and I dumped the enviromnent and loaded it in the adb shell, the loaded python still could not load any libraries from standard library, like random.

Loading standard libraries from QPython console works just fine. Any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got python to work by following the provided link, http://wiki.qpython.org/hacker/#how-to-execute-qpythons-python-in-other-terminals, prepending all lines in the script with `export`, then running as root "`. /sdcard/qpyenv.sh`".  Finally I could run "`python`" and "`import os`" and all warning at the top disappeared.

```
root@trelte:/ # . /sdcard/qpyenv.sh                                            
root@trelte:/ # python
Python 2.7.2 (default, Oct 25 2014, 20:52:15) 
[GCC 4.9 20140827 (prerelease)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>>
```

Comment: This, indeed, works. I actually did this steps myself, the problem was somewhere else, my shell somehow did not allow me to source PATH from the file, despite other environment variables being loaded just fine. Exporting PATH manually helped.

Comment: the above url is not reachable here anymore, and besides, I am not sure that works at all anyways. i could find a copy of the file in the archive: http://web.archive.org/web/20150301002329/http://wiki.qpython.org/hacker/ but it wouldn't work for me, i ended up calling `/data/data/com.hipipal.qpy3/files/bin/python-android5` directly.

Comment: Could you please add here the code that worked for you? i have added export before every line and only got syntax error.

Comment: Sorry this was quite a while ago and I don't have that phone anymore.  All I remember is I edited /sdcard/qpyenv.sh and prefixed each line with "export".  If there is any lines that start with hash (#) leave those alone.  The other lines would be of the format "export FOO=bar" or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience you only need to set two variables for this to work:

```
export PYTHONHOME=/data/data/org.qpython.qpy/files
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.:/data/data/org.qpython.qpy/files/lib/:/data/data/org.qpython.qpy/files/:/data/data/org.qpython.qpy/lib/
```

but you need to run as root so you can access things in `/data/data/org.qpython.qpy/`