# How to use Python in an adb shell?

Tags: android, python, android-ndk

After using `adb shell` and getting a root shell on an Android platform, I would like to run some Python scripts. Any suggestions on how to put a version of python there?

PS. I am using Ubuntu 14.04, if that matters.

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27572892/4186942) help you?

Comment: @bjiang Thanks. That looks promising. However, I am not able to access the reference link (http://wiki.qpython.org/hacker/#how-to-execute-qpythons-python-in-other-terminals)in that answer. Trying to see if I can find it anywhere else.